# Update a Scheduled Task Action using Powershell 4.0

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, action

I have already searched this site and also done a good amount of googling and I am unable to find a why to do this.

I want to be able to update the action/s on a scheduled task using PS 4.0.
I don't mind if it means an action to delete the current Action and adding a new one.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to replace the current action with a new action object in a scheduled task.

```
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe"
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName "YourTaskName" -Action $Action
```

This will set a new action to run `powershell.exe` in a scheduled task.

Comment: Sounds so easy   I will give it a go shortly and report back

Comment: Hi, I got the following error:   

`$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe"
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Test Task" -Action $Action
Set-ScheduledTask : Access is denied.
At line:2 char:1
+ Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Test Task" -Action $Action
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask) [Set-ScheduledTask], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070005,Set-ScheduledTask`

Comment: @GarethDoherty Run your powershell console as administrator.

Comment: Thank you @Richard